# @ConversationScoped between two beans in a JSF/PrimeFaces app

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6, conversation-scope

Here's my dilemma.  JSF/PrimeFaces web application.  I have a @ManagedBean bean I'll call RequestBean.java associated with request.xhtml.  I have a bean @ManagedBean called ResponseBean.java associated with response.xhtml.  RequestBean has a method something like List wlist = getWidgetList();

The elements in wList will populate the response.xhtml associated with ResponseBean.java.

I'm not allowed to use the Session attributes for this so it must, I believe involve @ConversationScoped.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial or example link for a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Conversations-Part-4) to be very helpful in understanding Conversations. I recommend reading through the first 3 parts of it also.

Also, I'd recommend checking out [CODI](https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/jsf-usage.html) , because JSF's Conversation scope is kind of limited. (Ex.: Cannot have parallel conversations, the managed conversation is shared among different `@ConversationScoped` beans - or anywhere it is injected)